# JS stops working when adding FORM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to close up comment box when I click "Cancel" button and also don't let post if there are 0 symbols in comment box. This code is working fine:

```
$(function () {
    $('.panel-google-plus > .panel-footer > .input-placeholder, .panel-google-plus > .panel-google-plus-comment > .panel-google-plus-textarea > button[type="reset"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var $panel = $(this).closest('.panel-google-plus');
        $comment = $panel.find('.panel-google-plus-comment');

        $comment.find('.btn:first-child').addClass('disabled');
        $comment.find('textarea').val('');

        $panel.toggleClass('panel-google-plus-show-comment');

        if ($panel.hasClass('panel-google-plus-show-comment')) {
            $comment.find('textarea').focus();
        }
    });
    $('.panel-google-plus-comment > .panel-google-plus-textarea > textarea').on('keyup', function(event) {
        var $comment = $(this).closest('.panel-google-plus-comment');

        $comment.find('button[type="submit"]').addClass('disabled');
        if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
            $comment.find('button[type="submit"]').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

And when I add FORM in html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/komentuoti/{{$p->id}}">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
  <div class="panel-google-plus-textarea form-group">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="60" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Rašykite komentarą"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success disabled">Post</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    <hr>
    <strong><h5>Komentarai</h5></strong>
    @foreach($p->comment as $com)
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>{{$com->user->name}}</strong> {{$com->body}}</li>
      </ul>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

The JS doesnt work anymore, the comment box won't close up. How to fix this ? It working fine without `<form></form>`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The JS code doesnt do functions if I add form tags around code.

Comment: Are you getting exceptions, and if so, what are they? That's probably the key part here.

Comment: I dont get nothing. Console is clear when I click button "Cancel". When there are not form tags it working fine. The comment box closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because the selector `.panel-google-plus-comment > .panel-google-plus-textarea` goes through correctly without the form inside, but fails with it. Consider the two snippets below:

```
<!-- Snippet 1 -->
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<!-- Snippet 2 -->
<div class="outer">
  <div class="hello">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the first snippet, the selector `.outer > .inner` matches because the `inner` element is a direct child of the `outer` element. In the second, the selector `.outer > .inner` does *not* match, because the `inner` is the `hello`'s child, not the `outer`'s. Instead, `.outer > .hello > .inner` would match, because `hello` is `outer`'s child, and `inner` is `hello`'s child.

Now, if you used `.outer .inner`, it would *not* be a problem in either case, because instead of trying to match direct children, all you care is that it's a descendant. That includes child like the first snippet, grandchild like the second snippet, great-grandchild, and so on. Or, in other words, `.outer .inner` would even match the `<input>` in this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <span class="what">
    <a class="in">
      <em class="the">
        <strong class="world">
          <form>
            <input class="inner">
          </form>
        </strong>
      </em>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

If you wanted to just use child selectors to get there, you'd have to use `.outer > .what > .in > .the > .world > form > .inner` at least.